# The difference between operators == and === in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, equality, equals-operator

Everyone who come across comparison of objects in JavaScript struggle a lot with this topic because this syntax(===) is not represented in any other popular languages. They only have == and that’s it.

The problem is that I can’t really understand the difference between === and == and the purpose of it. We don’t have anything like that in any other popular languages like python, Java or C++.

I would like to clearly understand the pros and cons of using === in my code if you have any useful articles or other pieces of information please share.

Comment: Strict Equality "===" : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality

Equality "==" : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality

This should help

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the only real difference is that `===` includes the type in the comparison; whereas `==` is just the value.

```
"6" == 6
```

Would be true, while:

```
"6" === 6
```

Would be false